# How to properly distance two radio buttons or checkboxes in the same row?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm a newbie in React Native and I'm working on a form to register an animal for adoption. Some fields are filled by choosing radio buttons and checkboxes, but in order to organize the form's layout I need to distance those elements of the form that are displayed in a row.

I tried to use:

1. `justify-content: 'space around'` - which didn't work because the label gets distanced from the button/box;
2. `paddingLeft`, `paddingRight` - kind of worked but as the buttons and boxes have labels with different numbers of characters, I can't get them aligned vertically like in the picture bellow without wasting a lot of time trying to set the correct padding.

Is there an easier way to do this?

[image: Buttons/Checkboxes must be like this]

Here is my code:

```html
<Text>SEXO</Text>
<View style = {{flexDirection: 'row', alignSelf: "auto"}}>
    <RadioButton checked={machoCheck} onPress={radioSexoHandlerMacho} />
    <Text style={{marginRight: 20}}>Macho</Text>
    <RadioButton checked={femeaCheck} onPress={radioSexoHandlerFemea}/>
    <Text>Femea</Text>
</View>

<Text>PORTE</Text>
<View style = {{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <RadioButton checked={pequenoCheck} onPress={radioPorteHandlerPequeno}/>
    <Text style={{paddingRight: 20}}>Pequeno</Text>
    <RadioButton checked={medioCheck} onPress={radioPorteHandlerMedio}/>
    <Text style={{paddingRight: 20}}>Medio</Text>
    <RadioButton checked={grandeCheck} onPress={radioPorteHandlerGrande}/>
    <Text>Grande</Text>
</View>

<Text>IDADE</Text>
<View style = {{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <RadioButton checked={filhoteCheck} onPress={radioIdadeHandlerFilhote}/>
    <Text style={{paddingRight: 20}}>Filhote</Text>
    <RadioButton checked={adultoCheck} onPress={radioIdadeHandlerAdulto}/>
    <Text style={{paddingRight: 20}}>Adulto</Text>
    <RadioButton checked={idosoCheck} onPress={radioIdadeHandlerIdoso}/>
    <Text>Idoso</Text>
</View>

<Text>TEMPERAMENTO</Text>
<View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
    <CheckBox style = {{height: 25}}
        disabled={false}
        value={brincalhao}
        onValueChange={(newValue) => setBrincalhao(newValue)}
        tintColors={{true: '#000000', false: '#2f3130'}}
        />
    <Text>Brincalhão</Text>

    <CheckBox style = {{height: 25}}
        disabled={false}
        value={timido}
        onValueChange={(newValue) => setTimido(newValue)}
        tintColors={{true: '#000000', false: '#2f3130'}}
        />
    <Text>Tímido</Text>

    <CheckBox style = {{height: 25}}
        disabled={false}
        value={calmo}
        onValueChange={(newValue) => setCalmo(newValue)}
        tintColors={{true: '#000000', false: '#2f3130'}}
        />
    <Text>Calmo</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the use of `<label>`?

Comment: Not yet. I searched a bit about it but i couldn't find any tips about it in React Native.

Comment: Consider looking at https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button_group and https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/input#label with the idea that button groups can either be single select(radio buttons) or multiple select(checkboxes)

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this,

like each item is wrapped in a `fragment` tag.

```
<View style = {{flexDirection: 'row', padding:5, justifyContent:"space-between"}}>
    <>
     <RadioButton checked={machoCheck} onPress={radioSexoHandlerMacho} />
     <Text style={{marginRight: 20}}>Macho</Text>
   </>
   <>
    <RadioButton checked={femeaCheck} onPress={radioSexoHandlerFemea}/
    <Text>Femea</Text>
   </>
</View>
```

Comment: Definitely, the above example is for purely understanding purpose. if I was reviewing this code, I would never accept and there is a scope of refactoring like reusing these items and delegating them as components.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I tried this way, but the button's label is getting distanced from the button. I need them to be like:  button label - space - button label